# Error trying to use filter() with ggplot()

Tags: r, database, ggplot2

So, I'am trying to use the `filter()` with `ggplot()` in R with this code:

`` LIST %>% filter(LIST %in% YEAR==c("2019","2020")) %>% group_by(`YEAR`, `Month`,`Line`,UF,`Segment`,`Fai`) %>% summarise(sum(qtd))%>% ggplot() + geom_col(aes(x=YEAR, y=`sum(qtd)`)) ``

Or this one:

`` LIST %>% group_by(`YEAR`, `Month`,`Line`,UF,`Segment`,`Fai`) %>% summarise(sum(qtd)) %>% filter(LIST %in% YEAR==c("2019","2020")) %>% ggplot() + geom_col(aes(x=YEAR, y=`sum(qtd)`)) ``

For both of them I receive the same error:

`` Error: Problem with `filter()` input `..1`. ``

`` i Input `..1` is `LIST %in% YEAR == c("2019", "2020")`. ``

`` x Input `..1` must be of size 12396 or 1, not size 33. ``

`` Run `rlang::last_error()` to see where the error occurred. ``

`In addition: Warning message:`

`In LIST %in% YEAR == c("2019", "2020") :`

`longer object length is not a multiple of shorter object length`

*Only as information, this database has 33 columns and 12396 lines*

This code works without the `filter()` function on it, but them I need to filter and save the database before doing the plot, so I really would like to understand the why it isn't working

The code with `filter()`used before de plot code

`LIST<-filter(LIST %in% YEAR==c("2019","2020"))`

`` LIST %>% group_by(`YEAR`, `Month`,`Line`,UF,`Segment`,`Fai`) %>% summarise(sum(qtd))%>% ggplot() + geom_col(aes(x=YEAR, y=`sum(qtd)`)) ``

Comment: It should be `LIST %<% filter(YEAR %in% c("2019", "2020")`, where list is your table.

Comment: So, it didn't worked out. I'am receiving this error: `could not find function "%<%"`

Comment: Sorry, my pipe was wrong - it should be greater than: `%>%`. So 
`library(tidyverse)` and then `LIST %>% filter(YEAR %in% c("2019", "2020")`.